# Reddit-like voting system in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, redux, voting-system

I'm trying to create reddit-like voting system inside of React. . I'm creating a bigger application which involves Redux and I'm trying to pass current score as props to the Voting component and save the outcome to the store. I've run into a wall and I cannot figure out the proper way to do so.

Should I handle the algorithm inside reducer and only dispatch actions from Voting component **or** should the component keep its own local state and only dispatch actions with the current score as argument?

> Here's my old implementation I created in the past. It's a simple
>   voting system which for its purposes worked just fine. However it was
>   never really storing saving the outcome, just displayed it inside DOM:
>   var React = require('react');

```
var Voting = React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
      number: liczba,
      upvote: 'upvote',
      downvote: 'downvote'
    };
  },
  getInitialState: function () {
    return{
      upvoted: false,
      downvoted: false
    };
  },
  upvote: function () {
    this.setState({
      upvoted: !this.state.upvoted,
      downvoted: false
    });
  },
  downvote: function () {
    this.setState({
      upvoted: false,
      downvoted: !this.state.downvoted
    });
  },
  render: function () {
    var {number, upvote, downvote} = this.props;
    var {upvoted, downvoted} = this.state;

    function voting(){
      if(upvoted){
        number++;
        upvote = 'upvote-active';
      } else if(downvoted){
        number--;
        downvote = 'downvote-active';
      }
    };

    voting();
    return(
      <div className="vote">
        <div className={upvote} onClick={this.upvote}></div>
        <div className="score">{number}</div>
        <div className={downvote} onClick={this.downvote}></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = Voting;
```